# Horizontal Scroll Animation that Stops and Starts

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm having trouble with an animation that continuously scrolls until the user hovers over one of the images. When the user hovers off the image the function containing the animation starts again. The problem is that since the animation is determined by the size of the margin and the duration is set to a static number, when the animation starts again it will always take 15000 milliseconds to finish no matter how small the margin gets. So when the user hovers over an image when it's almost off the page the whole animation slows down significantly. Are there ideas on how I can make the duration of the animation relative to the size of the margin? Here's a link to what I'm talking about http://nusuth.com/testportfol.html

HTML

```
<div class="content-bar">
<div id="bar-child">
    <div class="portthumb"><img src="images/chw1.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
    <div class="portthumb"><img src="images/dg1.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
    <div class="portthumb"><img src="images/chw1.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#bar-child :first").animate({
        marginLeft: -600,
        }, {
        duration: 15000,
        easing: 'linear',
        complete: function() {
            $(this).css('margin-left', 0).add($(this).last()).appendTo("#bar-child")
            loop()
        }
        })
};

$(document).ready(function() {
loop()  
})

$(".portthumb").hover(function() {
    $("#bar-child :first").stop()
}, function() {
            loop();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a good idea to use css3 animations or transitions rather than animating with javascript. http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/transitions-animations/

To answer the original question:
You could calculate the time based on the margin. For example something like:

```
duration: 25 * ( 600 + parseInt($("#bar-child :first").css('margin-left')) )
```

When the left margin is 0 the duration is 25 * 600 = 15 000

When the left margin is -300 the duration is 25 * (600 - 300) = 7 500